# Unable to show the polygon I've drawn in PyQGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgsmapcanvas, qgsrubberband

I'm using for my first time `QgsMapCanvas()` and when I write my script and I then run it, I don't see anything in the canvas.
That's my script:

```
canva = QgsMapCanvas()
r = QgsRubberBand(canva,True)
points = [[QgsPointXY(607826.87000000011175871, 380922.09400000004097819),
           QgsPointXY(607846.87000000011175871, 380922.09400000004097819),
           QgsPointXY(607846.87000000011175871, 380952.09400000004097819)]]
r.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(points),None)

r.show()
canva.show()
```

Any help from you?

Comment: Try just after defining `r` : `r.setWidth(1)` and `r.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))`, and `canva = iface.mapCanvas()`.

Comment: Make it an answer I think

Comment: imho the solution is setting the canvas extent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the extent of your `QgsMapCanvas` object.

Simply add the following line:

```
canva.setExtent(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(points).boundingBox())
```

By the way, if you wish to zoom out slightly from the polygon extent, you can use the method `zoomByFactor()`

E.g. running:

```py
canva = QgsMapCanvas()
r = QgsRubberBand(canva,True)
points = [[QgsPointXY(607826.87000000011175871, 380922.09400000004097819),
           QgsPointXY(607846.87000000011175871, 380922.09400000004097819),
           QgsPointXY(607846.87000000011175871, 380952.09400000004097819)]]
r.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(points),None)
canva.setExtent(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(points).boundingBox())
canva.zoomByFactor(1.1)
r.show()
canva.show()
```

from the Python console results in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That's working fine.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it solved your problem (click the check mark). https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers